# Saving mixed types of entries in one variable in R

Tags: r, readxl

I am importing a big database from an excel document.
In one of the columns, I have entries that are either numbers or numbers and characters.
for example:

```
Column1 | Column2  
a       |  1  
a       |  2  
a       |  3  
     .  
     .  
a       |  1999  
a       |  1A  
a       |  1B  
     .  
     .
```

So the problem is the saving of the second column.
The code I use is:

```
document <- read_excel(path,"Sample")    
values <- unique(document$Column2)
```

But, I notice that only the numeric values are saved and the last one (the first with a character) as **NA**.
I tried to fix this by telling him to interpret the values as characters:

```
 values <- unique(as.character(document$Column2))
```

However, this did not solve the problem. Any suggestions on how could I fix the code?

Comment: Try setting argument `col_types` to the column types when reading from the file. See `help('read_excel')`.

Comment: yes, that did the trick. Thanks